# Initialize Gazebo_ros_controll plugin with a custom hardware interface and the standard interfaces

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-ros-control

I'm building a Ackermann Vehicle in Gazebo and therefore I implemented a custom hardware_interface for the gazebor_ros_control plugin.

Now I want to use a simple VelocityJointController in addition to the existing Controller for another functionality on the same robot. But when I try to launch everything, I get the following error

> This controller requires a hardware interface of type 'hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface'. Make sure this is registered in the hardware_interface::RobotHW class"

I think that the default interfaces like EffortJoint-/JointState/- and VelocityJoint Interface aren't loaded. Does someone know how to fix this problem?

```xml
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
        <robotSimType>steer_bot_hardware_gazebo/SteerBotHardwareGazebo</robotSimType>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```